# What is the purpose and function of the dereference operator in this map?

Tags: c++

std::map< int, std::vector< RAddr > * > writeSetList;

I understand how the map works for instance that the keys are of type int and that the values are of type vector that holds a user defined type "Raddr" and that the name of the map is writeSetList. What I dont understand is what that dereference operator is doing. Is the value type a pointer to a vector? Thanks in advance. I couldn't find any examples like this...

Comment: that means second(value) is a pointer, right?

Comment: yes so if you are using the first and second map functions i.e. writeSetList.second (not sure what their proper names are...member functions?) the second would return a pointer to a vector is how im understanding it now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not the *dereference* operator, but rather a declaration of a pointer type. The map binds an `int` to a `std::vector<RAddr>*`, that is a pointer to a vector of `RAddr`

Answer (score 0):

It's a map of `int` to *pointer* to `std::vector< RAddr >`. The `*` is not a dereference operator, it signifies a pointer type.